# How to prevent a -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: : index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] crash from occuring in this situation

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, crash

```
UITableViewCell* cell=[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point]];
```

This is the line that my App crashes on. Is there any tips or suggestion on how to prevent the crash from occuring. Perhaps not executing this piece of code at all if index is beyond array.

Comment: Split the code into two lines. Check the return value of `indexPathForRowAtPoint`.

Comment: I am thinking if the point is not visible, what would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot guarantee that `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` will return a valid index path, so validate it before using it:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
if (indexPath) {
    UITableViewCell* cell=[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```